# Deleting adjacent repeating characters in a string

Tags: python, string

I want to delete adjacent repeating characters in a string in Python 3. For ex if the input is `AABBC` the output is `ABC` or if the input is `AAABBBCC` the output is `ABC`. I made two attempts to solve this problem.

Attempt #1

```
string = input()

for i in range (len(string) - 1):
    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
        string.replace(string[i],"")

print(string)
```

The above code returns the same string that is entered. If I enter `AABBC` it simply returns the same string. Not knowing what I was doing wrong, I tried another attempt.

Attempt #2

```
string = input()

new = []

for i in string:
    new.append(i)

for i in range (len(new) - 3):
    """in the above line, if I set the range to (len(new)-2), it gives me an 
    error saying "list index out of range"."""
    if new[i] == new[i+1]:
        new.pop(i)

print(new)
```

The above code works for double repeating characters, but fails when there are 3 or more repeating characters. If I input `AABBC` it returns the list `['A','B','C']` which is perfectly fine, but with the input `AAABBCC` it returns `['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex:

```
import re

s = ["AABBC", "AAABBBCC"]
for i in s:
    print( re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r"\1", i) )
```

---

**Or:**

```
s = ["AABBC", "AAABBBCC"]
for i in s:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        if not temp:
            temp.append(j)
        else:
            if temp[-1] != j:
                temp.append(j)
    print("".join(temp))
```

**Output:**

```
ABC
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` to group the `char`acters like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby('AABBCC')]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'AAABBBCC'

result = ''

for letter in string:
    if len(result) > 0:
        if result[-1] != letter:    # [-1] is the last letter
            result += letter
    else:
        result = letter    # the first letter will always be included

print(result)    # ABC
```

That is, only append the letter if it is not already at the end of the result string.

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand short solution :

```
 mot = 'AABBBCC'
 a = [mot[0]] + [mot[i] if mot[i]!=mot[i-1] else '' for i in range(1, len(mot))]
 >>> ['A', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', '']

 result = ''
 for lettre in a:
     result += lettre
 result
 >>> 'ABC'
```

You first create a list of the letters which respects a certain condition, then you convert this list into a string. This algorithm can be used for many different conditions.

Note that you don't need to import any new library.